# How can I upload an image to firebase storage and add it to the database?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, image-uploading

I'm new to Vuejs. I want to have a form using which you can add products. The product image goes to firebase storage but how do I associate that image with the exact product in the database?

I've already set up my form, and created two methods. saveProduct() to save the products to the database and onFilePicked() to listen for changes in the input field and target the image and upload that to storage.

```
import { fb, db } from '../firebaseinit'
export default {
  name: 'addProduct',
  data () {
    return {
      product_id: null,
      name: null,
      desc: null,
      category: null,
      brand: null,
      image: null,
    }
  }, 
  methods: {
    saveProduct () {
      db.collection('products').add({
        product_id: this.product_id,
        name: this.name,
        desc: this.desc,
        category: this.category,
        brand: this.brand
      })
      .then(docRef => {
        this.$router.push('/fsbo/produkten')    
      })

    },
    onFilePicked (event) {
      let imageFile = event.target.files[0]
      let storageRef = fb.storage().ref('products/' + imageFile.name)
      storageRef.put(imageFile)
    }  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself. Here's my solution. I don't know if it's technically correct but it works for my use case.

```
methods: {
saveProduct () {
  let imageFile
  let imageFileName
  let ext 
  let imageUrl
  let key
  let task
  db.collection('products').add({
    product_id: this.product_id,
    name: this.name,
    desc: this.desc,
    category: this.category,
    brand: this.brand
  })
  .then(docRef => {
    key = docRef.id
    this.$router.push('/fsbo/produkten')
    return key    
  })
  .then(key => {
    if(this.image !== null) {
      this.onFilePicked
      imageFile = this.image
      imageFileName = imageFile.name
      ext = imageFileName.slice(imageFileName.lastIndexOf('.'))
    }
    let storageRef = fb.storage().ref('products/' + key + '.' + ext)
    let uploadTask = storageRef.put(imageFile)
    uploadTask.on('state_changed', (snapshot) => {}, (error) => {
      // Handle unsuccessful uploads
    }, () => {
      uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then( (downloadURL) => {
        db.collection('products').doc(key).update({ imageUrl: downloadURL})
      });
    });     
  })    
},
onFilePicked (event) {
  return this.image = event.target.files[0]
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

what about this, you can use the filename, your images are going to be served as `somefireurl.com/{your_file_name}` on your product collection you can have an image prop with the `imageFile.name`.

```
 methods: {
    saveProduct (image = null) {
      let productRef = db.collection('products').doc(this.product_id)
      const payload = {
        product_id: this.product_id,
        name: this.name,
        desc: this.desc,
        category: this.category,
        brand: this.brand
      }
      if (image) payload['image'] = image
      return productRef
      .set(payload, {merge: true})
      .then(docRef => {
        this.$router.push('/fsbo/produkten')    
      })

    },
    onFilePicked (event) {
      let imageFile = event.target.files[0]
      let storageRef = fb.storage().ref('products/' + imageFile.name)
      storageRef.put(imageFile)
      return this.saveProduct(imageFile.name)
    }  
  }
```

That should be enough to get you started, maybe you want to try a different combination, or maybe you dont want to call saveProduct the way I set it, it's up to your use case but the idea is the same. Hope this can help you

Comment: Hi, thankyou for helping me out. But I am getting productRef.set(..) is not a function which is weird

Comment: can I see how `db` looks like? it should be something like `const db = admin.firestore()` where admin is your firebase instance

Comment: I have the following: import firebase from 'firebase'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import firebaseConfig from './firebaseConfig'
import 'firebase/storage'

const fb = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const db = firebase.firestore();

export {fb, db}

Comment: Ups! I missing the doc id, u are letting firebase to set the doc id for you, you have a few options here, change set for add, or even better, see my update example

Comment: Hii, sorry for reacting late. `return productRef.add(payload, {merge: true})` When I do this, I receive an error of CollectionReference.add() requires 1 argument, but was called with 2 arguments.